# Two steps search to search document with similar vectors in Solr

Tags: vector, solr

I am thinking to find documents in Solr that have similar vectors.

1. A user enters a few keywords
2. A list of documents that have the keywords will be reported by Solr based on Solr's scoring alogrithms.
3. The user then select a couple of documents as the reference documents.
4. Solr will then search for documents that have close correlation (similar vectors) to the selected couple of documents.

For the first 3 steps, I know how to do it.  But have no clue how to perform step 4. I have read [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Term+Vector+Component][1], but still not sure how to perform step 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two approaches.  The first is to use search results clustering. You first search by the keywords then ask solr to cluster the results. Present to the user the list of clusters and thier documents.

The second approach is to use multiple requests of the more like this handler and merge the results.  In each request,  you use a document from the reference documents that the user has marked.

Comment: I just tried building a small index to verify MLT (more like this) handler.  The result and performance is satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

The step 4 sounds like a [More Like This](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/MoreLikeThis) function, which already ships with Solr.